# Prove that the set of solutions to the system of equations $x' = A(t)x$ is a linear space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $A$ be a continuous function defined on the interval $(a, b), a < b$, whose values are $n \times n$ matrices. Prove that the set of solutions to the system of equations $x' = A(t)x$ is a linear space. Find its dimension.

**My try:**
We can prove all the axioms of linear space (commutativity, associativity, zero vector...), for example: $$\frac d{dt}(x+y)=\dot x+\dot y=A(t)x+A(t)y=A(t)(x+y),$$ so $x+y$ is also a solution.

However, I think there is a smarter way to do this than proving the 8 axioms, anyone have any idea?

Comment: Apart from what you already have you just need $(cx)'=cx'=cA(t)x=A(t)(cx)$. Rest of the verifications  are trivial.

Answer (score 1):

The set of continuous functions on $(a, b)$ already form a vector space under pointwise addition and multiplication by scalars. So to show that this subset is a vector space under those operations, ie a vector subspace, it suffices to show that it is closed under the two operations. You have already shown that if $x$ and $y$ are solutions then so is $x + y$. It is just as easy to show that $\lambda x$ is a solution for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$:
$$\frac{d}{dt}(\lambda x) = \lambda \dot{x} = \lambda A(t) x = A(t)(\lambda x)$$

Comment: Great, thank you very much! Could you please help me find the dimension of this space?

Comment: @qerty149 I think that should be a separate question, in which you should include as context what you know about the existence and uniqueness of solutions to such equations.